# Fill column in Julia

Tags: r, julia

I am trying to fill a column in Julia with values from another matrix. In R, it would look like this:

```
for(id in 1:y){
    countries[id,1] <- x[id, countries1[id]]
}
```

However, when I try to convert the left side of the equal sign to Julia like so:

```
countries[:1]
```

I get an error which says:

```
"ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an 
object of type Array{Int64,2}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Array{Int64,2} . 
(...), since type constructors fall back to convert methods."
```

I don't think my Julia conversion in correct to start with since I am leaving off id. How can I convert the r code to Julia effectively?

Comment: @PicaudVincent Unofrtunately I get that same error.

Comment: `for id in 1:y countries[id,1]=x[id,countries1[id]] end` does not work? (it assumes that `y` is a size (integer)

Comment: @PicaudVincent Nope...y is an integer, but I get the same error.

Comment: that's strange, I do not understand. Maybe you can add the result of typeof(countries) typeof(countries1) typeof(x) typeof(y) to your question so that we can check types

Comment: This sounds a lot like a syntax issue. The best thing you could do is to post an MWE, ie something we can just cut-and-paste into the REPL that will reproduce the error. So you will need to initialize `countries` and `countries1` in the MWE. I suspect it will be an easy fix once you've done that.

Comment: Additionally - one possibly tricky thing in your current question formulation is that `countries[:1]` is the same as `countries[1]` as `:1` in julia gets parsed simply as an integer 1.

Comment: @PicaudVincent Upon running typeof() I found that x was an array of an array which was causing my problem...it was that simple! Thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: @Ellie You are welcome, happy that the problem is solved and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear how the OP intends to convert the stated R code to Julia code. However, given that it involves `countries[:1]`, we can make an educated guess about the error:

`countries[:1]` should be `countries[:, 1]`.

- `countries[:, 1]` returns the first **column** in the matrix `countries`.
- `countries[:1]` resolves to `countries[1]` and returns the **integer** `countries[1,1]`. This is because a leading colon `:<name>` tells Julia to treat `<name>` as a symbol. At some point that symbol is parsed, returning 1.

The latter point explains the error message:

> ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an 
>   object of type Array{Int64,2}

The OP expected `countries[:1]` to return an array (*Array{Int64,2}*) , when in fact, it returns an integer (*Int64*).